# Add a tag to multiple work items

Tags: rtc, jazz, rational-team-concert

I'm working with multiple tickets in RTC and have so far successfully multi-updated fields like filed against, status etc. However I see no option to multi-update the tags field.

I have hundreds of tickets I need to add tags to. Is there a way of doing a multi-update on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently missing feature in RTC web interface. See [Enhancement 219534: add support for bulk edit of attribute "Tags" in work items on Web](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=219534). Anyway it is possible in Eclipse client. You can try it.